# CSS not being minified when bundling in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, bundle, minify

I have two large CSS files and two large JS files. I have included them all within their own bundles you can see below: (note the use of CssMinify class was just added to see if it made a difference, it doesn't)

[image]

When I enable optimisations I can see the following in dev tools:

[image]

And when I disable optimisations I can see the following:

[image]

From what I can see, the JS files are being bundled and minified. You can tell this by the dodgey path and the fact that the size of the JS files are much smaller when optimisations is set to true. Plus when I check the response preview I can clearly see the JS is minified. Great.

However, my CSS is not being minified! This should be apparent as the CSS files are the same size in both images provided. Also, when I check the response it is clearly not minified CSS.

What have I missed? Why isn't it minifying my CSS like it is with my JS?

EDIT: I just found about 8 of these in my the dev tools preview at the top of the CSS file:

/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(8205,78): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '='/*

Comment: Have you checked the contents of the file in each case? I know that minification is not applied when in `web.config` the `debug` flag is set to true. Maybe this is the case

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code. Post code.

Answer (score 1):

If any of your CSS files are using an @import directive, then the CSS minifying process is known to fail as it will not follow the includes. This leaves you two options:

(1) Don't optimize your CSS files (esp. if you are not in control of them)

(2) Remove the @import statement(s) and amalgamate your CSS files

[Don’t use import-css directives when bundling](http://sde03.azurewebsites.net/index.php/2013/06/dont-use-import-css-directives-when-bundling/)

["Unexpected token found" on @import directives](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/191)

**EDIT**

In response to your edit in the question, it seems that "Bundler & Minifier doesn’t support CSS files with css variables". See here:

[VS minify css gives error: CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found '-'](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/51ba77f7-ec13-483b-98c8-65cb1735db7e/vs-minify-css-gives-error-css1062-expected-semicolon-or-closing-curlybrace-found-?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

Comment: Why shouldn't you optimise CSS files if you aren't in control of them?.. EDIT.. just noticed the link! Reading now!

Comment: Sometimes, front-end people are on a different team and in control of the structure of "their" CSS files. Changing the structure of the CSS files could also potentially affect the specificity rules depending on how they are written.

Comment: Ah I see, that's fair enough. In this situation however I am in control of the full stack and it's unlikely that'd change!

Comment: I came across this problem a few years ago and I "personally" consider it a bug. MS has not addressed it for some unknown reason. Basically, you can fix it by not using @import statements ;-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54088086/912287 solved my problem.